# Select query to populate a field from another key/value table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Table_1

```
pid |   decs_key
-------------------------
1   |   1022
2   |   1028
3   |   1022
4   |   1022
5   |   1022
```

Table_2

```
desc_key|   decs_value
-------------------------
1022    |   'desc 1'
1028    |   'desc 2'
1029    |   'desc 3'
1088    |   'desc 4'
```

How to write a SELECT query that returns following result set:

```
1   |   'desc 1'
2   |   'desc 2'
3   |   'desc 1'
4   |   'desc 1'
5   |   'desc 1'
```

Comment: Look up `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select table1.pid, table2.decs_value
from table1 
join table2 
on table1.decs_key = table2.decs_key
```